# Black Output for DeepLab Semantic Segmentation on Custom Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

First of all, I'd like to say that I'm pretty new to Tensorflow & Python.

I am currently trying to retrain mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug DeepLab semantic segmentation model from the Tensorflow model zoo on my own custom dataset. I used Labelme to generate the output masks of my 360 image dataset and followed the steps given by this article to successfully train the model for 5000 steps with a loss of ~0.87. However, after running vis.py, all the outputs of my 37 evaluation images are black masks. Running the output mask through numpy confirmed that all pixel values were = 0.

Here is my Dataset_generator.py:

```
_PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 80, # Rewrite to the number of training image files
        'train_aug': 10582, #　OK as it is
        'trainval': 90, # Rewrite to the total number of image files
        'val': 10, # Rewrite to the number of verification image files
    },
    num_classes=2, #　Number of classes (1 = block) + background (1)
    ignore_label=255, #　OK as it is
)
```

My num_classes = 2, since I only have 1 other object labeled (a block) + the background.

I read through all the github "issues" threads on this issue but nothing seems to work. I tried setting different weights as they suggested, but only yielded the same results. Here is my train.py command:

```
!python /content/models/research/deeplab/train.py --logtostderr \
   --training_number_of_steps=1000 \
   --train_split="train" \
   --model_variant="mobilenet_v2" \
   --output_stride=16 \
   --decoder_output_stride=4 \
   --train_crop_size="513,513" \
   --min_resize_value=513 \
   --max_resize_value=513 \
   --train_batch_size=4 \
   --dataset="pascal_voc_seg" \
   --train_logdir="/content/Tensorflow-Object-Detection-API-train-custom-Mask-R-CNN-model/images/seg dataset/checkpoint" \
   --dataset_dir="/content/Tensorflow-Object-Detection-API-train-custom-Mask-R-CNN-model/images/seg dataset/tfrecord" \
   --fine_tune_batch_norm=False \
   --initialize_last_layer=False \
   --last_layers_contain_logits_only=True \
   --label_weights=1 \
   --label_weights=10 \
```

The dataset annotation mask (in SegmentationClassRaw folder) seems to be generated correctly as it is a black image with 0 as the background and 1 as the label. The train.txt, val.txt, and trainval.txt are also listing the appropriate file names without extensions.

Lastly, I have also retrained the model multiple times, setting weights to different values, and even tried models with a loss as low as 0.21. Everything output a black mask.

I am honestly stumped as to what else I can try. Please let me know if anyone has any ideas. Thank you in advance.